# Jhipster : send date and time value to server

Tags: jhipster

With Jhipster, I want to send to the server an object with a property that represents Date and Time : 2018-03-07 11:25:23'.

In Jhipster there is the DateUtils function that can convert to 'yyyy-MM-dd'.
When I change the pattern to 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' I am getting an internal server error (with no error log on server side).

How can I send the time with the date to Spring MVC?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look How I deal with dates: https://codefitter2.blogspot.com/2018/02/how-to-solve-typeerror-datesplit-is-not.html, https://codefitter2.blogspot.com/2018/02/how-to-pass-current-client-datetime-to.html

Comment: In Jhipster I think it has something to do with JacksonConfiguration class.